# Finding lower $\ell_{q}$ estimates for weighted scalar subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

Here is a stumper.  Define $c_{00}$ as the space of all finitely-supported real sequences, i.e. all sequences $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n\neq 0$ for only finitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Question 1 (the simplified version).**  For which $q\in(1,\infty)$ does the inequality
\begin{equation}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|^q\right)^{1/q}\leq\sup_{n_1<n_2<\cdots\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{|a_{n_k}|}{k}\end{equation}
hold for all sequences $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in c_{00}$?

**Question 2 (the fully generalized version).**  Fix $1\leq p<\infty$.  For which $q\in(p,\infty)$ does there exist a positive real number $C=C(p,q)$ such that
\begin{equation}\tag{$*$}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|^q\right)^{1/q}\leq C\sup_{n_1<n_2<\cdots\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left|\frac{a_{n_k}}{k}\right|^p\right)^{1/p}\end{equation}
for all sequences $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in c_{00}$?

*Note that question 1 is just question 2 with $C=p=1$.*

**Also note:**  I would be very happy with partial answers.  For instance, can we just find some $p$, $q$, and $C$ so that $(*)$ holds? Or so that $(*)$ fails to hold?

Comment: Allowing for $\Bbb K=\Bbb C$ does not add anything to this. After all, only  $|a_n|$ is used

Comment: True enough, thank you!  Fixed.